# How do I use an existing public key for PGP encryption with java?

Tags: bouncycastle, pgp

I have been reading examples on implementing PGP encryption using bouncy castle lib. First step seems to be creation of a public keyring file which eventually has the public key. Can someone please help me understand how to add an existing public key to the PublicKeyRing?

Comment: There are 2 fine articles that describe the key generation, import a 3rd party public key, encryption and signing: https://www.codesandnotes.be/2018/07/17/openpgp-java-keys-generation/ and https://www.codesandnotes.be/2018/09/04/openpgp-integration-java-and-javascript-java-pgp-encryption/. The complete source code is available as well and it is running with the latest Bouncy Castle libs (version 1.66).

Comment: Okay, Thanks a lot :) will go through these.